# What would be the gravitational force of attraction between two masses which are not both point masses?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry

I know for a planet (of mass $M$) and a point mass, we can say the field from planet on the outside is like that of a point mass so the formula of attraction is just $GMm/r^2$. But if that is not a point mass - let's say it has mass $m$ and radius $R$ and the planet too has radius $R$ (spherical both) - then will also the force be equal to $GMm/r^2$ where $r \geq 2R$  or something different? Is it possible to arrive at the result with only vectors (integration answer also accepted if logically cant be concluded ))?

Comment: See also https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/GravField.htm

Comment: Sir that link explain the field generated when only one spherical mass is there outside , it doesnt depicts how the field behaves when two not point masses r there isnt ?

Comment: actually it kind of does. There is mention of the principle of superposition where the two gravitational potentials just add up, and this is how they treat non-point masses (Like in a ring). In your case, you have two distinct mass clumps, but the same process applies.

Comment: I see thanks Sir , btw the integration method would involve integration a force of form k/r^2 on a entire sphere is there a logical way to conclude whole force would be acting like on the centre of mass of other sphere ?

Comment: The gravitational field of solid spherical bodies outside the body is identical to that of a point mass, so all you have to do is superimpose the field of two point masses and you have your answer.

Comment: Yeah sir outside of both its easy to calculate net field by superposition i am asking for force of attraction between two so needed integration isnt of the force k/r^2 on an entire sphere?

Comment: Are you asking about a contact pair? Like asteroid [Ultima Thule](https://www.zmescience.com/science/news-science/nasa-spacecraft-ulma-thule-043053/) ??

Comment: No Sir can u show by integration of k/r^2 force on the other sphere gives the forcs of attraction to be like point masses both ? I will upvote it , i am editing the question a bit as such i still didnt get without integration how logically we can conlcude fodce of attraction between the spheres to be that . @John_Alexiou

Comment: @John_Alexiou Sir u got what i meant from the above?

Comment: Maybe there us some connection where the com def (term) in the force expression might come out from the integral which would prove it acts at com of other?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not understand the question. Are you asking if the sum of the moments of gravitational force about the COM is zero?

Comment: I meant Sir take the one sphere to be at origin and now the field outside would of form k/r^2 , now i am asking to write this field in vector form so as when integration of that force over the other sphere, the dmr integral/integral dm sort of come out of the integral which shows its the COM of other where net force of attraction is acting .

Answer (score 2):

For spherically symetric masses the gravitational field for r>R
where R is the radius of the sphere would be the same for a Point mass.

For r<R the gravitational field is proportional to R,
meaning at the radius is a maximum, and r=0 the field is zero

This can be obtained using gauss law for gravitation, without a direct integration

Comment: Will not the field inside /outside be effected by other sphere outside ?

Comment: And using gauss law we needed a proof of that field is symmetrical even in case of two sphere system when considering inside and outside field ,which Sir u didnt tell/clarify how u assumed it

Comment: The principle of super position allows me to treat each sphere separately. So just considering the field due to one sphere , The field will be spherically symetric, because my mass is spherically symetric.

Comment: I see okay so both fields r like point massss at outside but for force calculation one needs the field needs to be integrated for force calculation all over the other sphere isnt ?

Comment: Cannot understand what you're saying, however I think you're asking if I want to calculate the force on one sphere due to the other  I would need to Integrate the field over the other sphere. that would be A way of doing it yes. however because it spherically symetric, The center of mass is in the geometric center. so the force on one sphere due to the other wouldn't need an integration, it would be exactly the same for point masses. (provided the spheres aren't touching eachother

Comment: For more complicated shapes you cannot solve this problem without integration

Comment: @Orion_Pax See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem for a deeper explanation of what happens if you tunnel beneath the surface of a gravitating body.

Comment: Keep in mind that the center of gravity coincides with the center of mass only in a uniform external field.

Comment: Yeah @jensen_paull Sir i get the point of superposition but the integration method would involve integration a force of form k/r^2 on a entire sphere is there a logical way to conclude whole force would be acting like on the centre of mass of other sphere?

Comment: @R.W. Bird Sir yeah so here field is field is non uniform of form k/r^2 so we cant conclude directly it will be at centre of mass isnt Sir?

Comment: I didnt get a feeling of why it should be centre of mass of other , may u provide just the integration one Sir i think thats the only way for me to understand/do this problem

Comment: I didnt get a feeling of why it should be centre of mass of other , may u provide just the integration one Sir i think thats the only way for me to understand/do this problem

Comment: Well first we need to determine the gravitational field due to e.g mass 1, which is $g(r) = \iiint  \frac{G \rho(r')  (\vec{r-r'})}{|r-r'|^3} d^3r' $

Comment: Where $\rho(r')$ is mass density, here we are integrating with respect to r'

Comment: Then I would take this, and compute the force $\iiint g(r)dm $Where dm is $  \rho_2(r) d^3r$

Comment: Hmm thanks @jensen_paull Sir , btw is there a connection between centre of mass definition(vector form) and force exerted from integration(in vector)( k/r^2 form )which can easily explain why it has to be COM of other sphere ?

Answer (score 0):

For Newtonian gravity, the acceleration of gravity generated by a point mass $M$ can be taken as the gradient of a scalar field: $\mathbf a = -\nabla \phi$, where $$\phi = -\frac{GM}{r}$$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2}$

What is clear calculating the derivatives, components of the gradient vector $$\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\right)$$

For the first one
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \frac{GMx}{(x^2 + y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

The gradient is
$$\nabla \phi = GM \frac{(x,y,z)}{(x^2 + y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = GM \frac{\mathbf r}{r^3} \implies \mathbf a = -GM \frac{\mathbf r}{r^3}$$ what is the Newton's law.

Now suppose that instead of a point mass, there is a spherical symmetric body. That symmetry implies that the scalar field must the same in any concentric spherical shell around the body. So, the shells are surfaces levels of $\phi$. The gradient is always orthogonal to surface levels, and must then be radial. And as the scalar field is the same, the modulus of the gradient must be also the same in each shell.

When the distance from the body tends to infinity, it can be approximated to a point mass, where the above equations are valid.

We must then conclude that for any distance $$\phi = -\frac{GM}{r}$$
where $r$ is the distance to the center of symmetry, and $M$ is the mass of the body.

Comment: Sir yeah def inside field when considering only one sphere is of form kr/r^3 , what i meant was integrating the outside field k/r^2 form from one sphere on another whole sphere so as to prove it acts at COM of other sphere . That was what i was expecting as calculation.